# Use await inside observable pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I my angular application I want to download pdf as `Blob` and process it to get `Uint8Array`.  I would like to do it in service which will return me rxjs `Observable<Uint8Array>` however I cant. I write following code

```
public loadBinaryPDF(url): Observable<Uint8Array>  {
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(map(async blob => {            
        let arrayBuff = await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer();    // some await here..
        return new Uint8Array(arrayBuff);
    }));
}
```

but get compilation error

```
ERROR in src/services/api-companies.service.ts(454,9): error TS2322: 
  Type 'Observable<Promise<Uint8Array>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Uint8Array>'.
Type 'Promise<Uint8Array>' is missing the following properties from type 'Uint8Array': 
  BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, buffer, byteLength, byteOffset, and 25 more.
```

So the problem is that I use `async-await` inside `pipe`/`map`. **How to fix it?** (I wan't to find the way which allow use async-await and return observable)

Comment: Why do you want to use async / await? The rxjs API is not to be used with `Promise`?

Comment: Your map function is async which wraps the return value again as a Promise. As a result you get `Observable<Promise<Uint8Array>>`. I personally don't recommend to mix Promise and Observables. Do one thing or another.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm do you know simpler alternative to convert `Blob` to `arrayBuffer`?

Comment: @HTN Where did you hear this? As far as I'm aware this isn't true at all - have you any source to back this claim up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just use as `switchMap` instead of a map.

```
public loadBinaryPDF(url): Observable<Uint8Array>  {
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(switchMap(async blob => {            
        let arrayBuff = await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer();
        return new Uint8Array(arrayBuff);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer :)

Comment: switchMap should return an observable. in here you do not do that !